# RedirectToAction doesn't redirect and instead returns call to View page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, redirecttoaction

I am trying to perform some operation on button click and after that it should redirect to another action. But it is not working and it returns control back to view.

JavaScript code

```
document.getElementById('newform').onsubmit = function ()
    {
        var model = new FormData();
        model.append("ID", '@Model.ID');

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Workflow/UpdateStatus",
            type: "POST",
            data: model,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (response) {

                if(!response.success)
                {
                    alert("here1");
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, error, thrown) {
                alert("here2" + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });

        return false;
    }
```

Controller code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UpdateStatus(string ID)
        {
            try
            {
                //Do_Something_Here;

                RedirectToAction("List", "Workflow", new { Id = "U" + ID });

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new
                {
                    success = false,
                    message = ex.Message,
                });
            }
        }
```

If I write `RedirectToAction` without `return` in controller then it says that not all codes paths return a value. If I use `return RedirectToAction` then instead of redirecting it goes back to JavaScript and prints on screen `here1`

Why is it not redirecting?

Comment: Could you please share the details of `"List", "Workflow"` where do you want to redirect? Share the details of that Action.

Comment: We cannot write directly `RedirectToAction` instead we should write `return  RedirectToAction();`

Comment: `List` action is simple and its code is just `return View();`. This is how it works. Press button, `UpdateStatus` action is called, then `return View();` of `List` is called (but it actually doesn't display `List` page and stays on current page. Then JavaScript alert is displayed on screen.

Comment: Okay, let me test, and provide you the suitable solution.

Comment: Well, I found the issue, if you want to redirect to the list page keeping your `ajax request` in that case you have update controller return type to json then need to return to new action from your `ajax` success method.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your point. By the way I just checked another project which I did earlier and it is using same code and it works fine.

Comment: Please check the solution, you can resolve your issue in following way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I write RedirectToAction without return in controller then it says
> that not all codes paths return a value. If I use return
> RedirectToAction then instead of redirecting it goes back to
> JavaScript and prints on screen here1

Well, as you are submiting ajax request which always expect a response and execute either of `success` or `error` this is why you are getting the `alert("here1");` because request `return 200 success code`. Altough it redirected to `List action` as its ajax request in client-side it always execute the success function.

**Solution:**

You have two way to handle this scenario and redirect to your desired action.

**Way:1**

Keeping the Ajax pattern: In this scenario, you have to return json just like below:

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UpdateStatus(string ID)
    {
        try
        {
            //Do_Something_Here;
            return Json(new {id = ID});
            
        }
```

View: Script:

```
$.ajax({
                url: "/Workflow/UpdateStatus",
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    'ID': 1
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);

                    window.location.href = "@Url.Action("List", "Workflow")?id=" + response.id;
                    if (!response.success) {
                        alert("here1");
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, error, thrown) {
                    alert("here2" + xhr.responseText);
                }
            });
```

Output:

[image]

**Way:2**

Asp.net core `form submit`

```
<form asp-controller="Workflow" method="post" asp-action="UpdateStatus">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input name="Id"  value="1"/>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateStatus(string ID)
        {
            try
            {

                return RedirectToAction("List", "Workflow", new { Id = "U" + ID });

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               
            }
        }
```

Output:

[image]

Either of the way would resolve your issue as expected.